# One - to - one call via WebRTC not work, setRemoteDescription error

Tags: javascript, sockets, webrtc

I wrote a code modeled on the tutorial -> https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab. Unfortunately, it works only half, or even. Now, after opening the first tab and permit the operation of the camera, the console throws:

```
This appears to be Chrome adapter.js:79
Create or join to room myroomname CallToUser.js:50
>>>  Room myroomname has 0 client(s) CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Request to create or join room myroomname CallToUser.js:74
Created room myroomname CallToUser.js:55
Adding local stream CallToUser.js:34
Client sending a message:  got user media CallToUser.js:84
>>>  Got message:  got user media
```

Once opened, while the other tabs, this throws:

```
This appears to be Chrome adapter.js:79
Create or join to room myroomname CallToUser.js:50
>>>  Room myroomname has 1 client(s) CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Request to create or join room myroomname CallToUser.js:74
User joined to room myroomname CallToUser.js:69
Adding local stream CallToUser.js:34
Client sending a message:  got user media CallToUser.js:84
>>>  Got message:  got user media CallToUser.js:74
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setRemoteDescription' of undefined CallToUser.js:102
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
Client received a message: [object Object] CallToUser.js:94
```

In contrast to the first console is added to the code:

```
    Another peer made request to join myroomname CallToUser.js:64
Client received a message: got user media CallToUser.js:94
Start call CallToUser.js:179
Client sending a message:  
RTCSessionDescription {sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 2709183428323234981 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s…8046 label:2f2f7c33-be63-4cff-8341-eabf2a30a775
↵", type: "offer"}
 CallToUser.js:84
>>>  Got message:  
Object {sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 2709183428323234981 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s…8046 label:2f2f7c33-be63-4cff-8341-eabf2a30a775
↵", type: "offer"}
 CallToUser.js:74
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.56.1 60969 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:2999745851 2 udp 2113937151 192.168.56.1 60969 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:3013953624 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.1.100 60970 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:3013953624 2 udp 2113937151 192.168.1.100 60970 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.56.1 60969 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:2999745851 2 udp 2113937151 192.168.56.1 60969 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:3013953624 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.1.100 60970 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:3013953624 2 udp 2113937151 192.168.1.100 60970 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.56.1 60969 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:2999745851 2 udp 2113937151 192.168.56.1 60969 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:3013953624 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.1.100 60970 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:3013953624 2 udp 2113937151 192.168.1.100 60970 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.56.1 60969 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:2999745851 2 udp 2113937151 192.168.56.1 60969 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:3013953624 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.1.100 60970 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:3013953624 2 udp 2113937151 192.168.1.100 60970 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:4233069003 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.56.1 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:4233069003 2 tcp 1509957375 192.168.56.1 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:4233069003 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.56.1 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:4233069003 2 tcp 1509957375 192.168.56.1 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:4233069003 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.56.1 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:4233069003 2 tcp 1509957375 192.168.56.1 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:4233069003 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.56.1 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:4247172264 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.1.100 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:4247172264 2 tcp 1509957375 192.168.1.100 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:4247172264 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.1.100 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
Client sending a message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:4247172264 2 tcp 1509957375 192.168.1.100 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:84
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:4233069003 2 tcp 1509957375 192.168.56.1 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:4247172264 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.1.100 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 0, id: "audio", candidate: "a=candidate:4247172264 2 tcp 1509957375 192.168.1.100 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:4247172264 1 tcp 1509957375 192.168.1.100 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
>>>  Got message:  Object {type: "candidate", label: 1, id: "video", candidate: "a=candidate:4247172264 2 tcp 1509957375 192.168.1.100 0 typ host generation 0
↵"} CallToUser.js:74
End of candidates
```

For any of the tabs is not added to the second part of the video caller. I suspect that this is happening because of this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setRemoteDescription' of undefined
```

However, I do not know how to deal with this error. Here is the code CallToUser.js and clipping of index.html

CallToUser.js:

```
//'use strict';

var CallToUser = function() {
    var isChannelReady;
    var isInitiator;
    var isStarted = false;
    var servers = null;
    var localStream;
    var localPeerConnection;
    var turnReady;
    var remoteStream;
    var pcConfig = {
        'iceServers': [{
            'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
            }]
        };
    var pcConstraints = {
        'optional': [{
            'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true
            }]
        };
    var sdpConstraints = {
        'mandatory': {
            'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
            'OfferToReceiveVideo': true
        }
    };
    var room;
    var socket = io.connect();

    var handleUserMedia = function(stream) {
        console.log('Adding local stream');
        document.getElementById('localVideo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        localStream = stream;
        sendMessage('got user media');
        if(isInitiator) {
            maybeStart();
        }
    };

    var handleUserMediaError = function(error) {
        console.log('getMediaError', error);
    };

    var createRoom = function(room) {
        room = room;
        if(room !== '') {
            console.log('Create or join to room', room);
            socket.emit('create or join', room);
        }

        socket.on('created', function(room) {
            console.log('Created room ' + room);
            isInitiator = true;
        });

        socket.on('full', function(room) {
            console.log('Room' + room + ' is full');
        });

        socket.on('join', function(room) {
            console.log('Another peer made request to join ' + room);
            isChannelReady = true;
        });

        socket.on('joined', function(room) {
            console.log('User joined to room ' + room);
            isChannelReady = true;
        });

        socket.on('log', function(array) {
            console.log.apply(console, array);
        });
    };

    var connect = function() {
        var constraints = {video: true};
        getUserMedia(constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);
    };

    var sendMessage = function(message) {
        console.log('Client sending a message: ', message);
        socket.emit('message', message);
    };

    window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
        sendMessage('bye');
    };

    var startCall = function() {        
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            console.log('Client received a message: ' + message);
            if(message === 'got user media') {
                maybeStart();
            } else if(message.type === 'offer') {
                if(!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
                    maybeStart();
                }

                localPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
                doAnswer();
            } else if(message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {
                var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
                    sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
                    candidate: message.candidate
                });

                localPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
            } else if(message === 'bye' && isStarted) {
                handleRemoteEndCall();
            }
        });

        if(location.hostname != 'localhost') {
            requestTurn('https://computeengineondemand.appspot.com/turn?username=41784574&key=4080218913');
        }
    };

    var maybeStart = function() {
        if(!isStarted && typeof localStream != 'undefined' && isChannelReady) {
            createPeerConnection();
            localPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
            isStarted = true;

            if(isInitiator) {
                doCall();
            }
        }
    };

    var createPeerConnection = function() {
        try {
            localPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
            localPeerConnection.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;
            localPeerConnection.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
            localPeerConnection.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log('exception ' + e.message);
            return;
        }
    };

    var handleIceCandidate = function(event) {
        if(event.candidate) {
            sendMessage({
                type: 'candidate',
                label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
                candidate: event.candidate.candidate
            });
        } else {
            console.log('End of candidates');
        }
    };

    var handleRemoteStreamAdded = function(event) {
        console.log('Remote stream added');
        document.getElementById('remoteVideo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
        remoteStream = event.stream;
    };

    var handleRemoteStreamRemoved = function(event) {
        console.log('Delete');
    };

    var handleCreateOfferError = function(event) {
        console.log('createOffer() error: ' + e);
    }

    var setLocalAndSendMessage = function(sessionDescription) {
        sessionDescription.sdp = preferOpus(sessionDescription.sdp);
        localPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
        sendMessage(sessionDescription);
    };

    var doCall = function() {
        console.log('Start call');
        localPeerConnection.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, handleCreateOfferError);
    };

    var doAnswer = function() {
        console.log('Sending answer');
        localPeerConnection.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, null, sdpContraints);
    };

    var endCall = function() {
        console.log('Hanging up');
        isStarted = false;
        localPeerConnection.close();
        localPeerConnection = null;
        sendMessage('bye');
    };

    var handleRemoteEndCall = function() {
    };

    var requestTurn = function(turnUrl) {
        var turnExists = false;

        for(var i in pcConfig.iceServers) {
            if(pcConfig.iceServers[i].url.substr(0, 5) === 'turn:') {
                turnExists = true;
                turnReady = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!turnExists) {
            console.log('Getting TURN server from ', turnUrl);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    var turnServer = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log('Got TURN server: ', turnServer);
                    pc_config.iceServers.push({
                        'url': 'turn:' + turnServer.username + '@' + turnServer.turn,
                        'credential': turnServer.password
                    });
                    turnReady = true;
                }
            };

            xhr.open('GET', turnUrl, true);
            xhr.send();
        }
    };

    var preferOpus = function(sdp) {
        var sdpLines = sdp.split('\r\n');
        var mLineIndex;

        for(var i = 0; i < sdpLines.length; i++) {
            if(sdpLines[i].search('m=audio') !== -1) {
                mLineIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(mLineIndex === null) {
            return sdp;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < sdpLines.length; i++) {
            if(sdpLines[i].search('opus/48000') !== -1) {
                var opusPayload = extractSdp(sdpLines[i], /:(\d+) opus\/48000/i);

                if(opusPayload) {
                    sdpLines[mLineIndex] = setDefaultCodec(sdpLines[mLineIndex], opusPayload);
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        sdpLines = removeCN(sdpLines, mLineIndex);

        sdp = sdpLines.join('\r\n');

        return sdp;
    };

    var extractSdp = function(sdpLine, pattern) {
        var result = sdpLine.match(pattern);

        return result && result.length === 2 ? result[1] : null;
    };

    var setDefaultCodec = function(mLine, payload) {
        var elements = mLine.split(' ');
        var newLine = [];
        var index = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)  {
            if(index === 3) {
                newLine[index++] = payload;
            }
            if(elements[i] !== payload) {
                newLine[index++] = elements[i];
            }
        }

        return newLine.join(' ');
    };

    var removeCN = function(sdpLines, mLineIndex) {
        var mLineElements = sdpLines[mLineIndex].split(' ');

        for(var i = sdpLines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var payload = extractSdp(sdpLines[i], /a=rtpmap:(\d+) CN\/\d+/i);

            if(payload) {
                var cnPos = mLineElements.indexOf(payload);

                if(cnPos !== -1) {
                    mLineElements.splice(cnPos, 1);
                }

                sdpLines.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        sdpLines[mLineIndex] = mLineElements.join(' ');

        return sdpLines;
    };

    return {
        connect: connect,
        startCall: startCall,
        endCall: endCall,
        createRoom: createRoom,
    };
};
```

index.html:

```
// some code
<script>        
            var calling = new CallToUser();
            calling.createRoom('myroomname');
            calling.connect();
            calling.startCall();
        </script>
```

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your process incoming message

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
            console.log('Client received a message: ' + message);
            if(message === 'got user media') {
                maybeStart();
            } else if(message.type === 'offer') {
                if(!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
                    maybeStart();
                }

                localPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
                doAnswer();
            }else if(message.type=="answer" && isStarted)
{ 
   localPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
} 
else if(message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {
                var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
                    sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
                    candidate: message.candidate
                });

                localPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
            } else if(message === 'bye' && isStarted) {
                handleRemoteEndCall();
            }
        });
```

Because when other peer accept offer its create answer with session description so you accept that answer and set to your local peer connection